# formulating conflicting optimization parameters

Tags: optimization

Imagine you are trying to solve an optimization problem and your goal is to pick a set of parameters, $p_1$ to $p_i$ that a given cost function $f$ is minimized based on a set of constraints.

What does it mean mathematically when two of these parameters are in conflict with each other meaning that picking any value for $p_n$ cause another parameter such as $p_m$ to be zero. in other words, they cannot coexist. This is probably the definition of "you can not have it all"!!

In other words, how to do we mathematically express and formulate conflicting optimization parameters?

Comment: I believe that such a 'conflict' is not really a conflict. It is a constraint. It means, that the two parameters must lie in some set, and are not `free' to be anything. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I guess it is a kind of a constraint but I am curious to see what that means from a mathematical perspective when we have such constraint? How do I even represent such constraint? How do you solve for such constraints? Thanks

Comment: Please give a specific example. It will help to address your question.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the constraint "$p_m p_n = 0$".  If that's not what you mean, you may need to provide a bit more detail in your Question.